# Spark Scala - Select columns after Full Outer Join

Tags: sql, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two DF's with same number and name of attributes. I performed Full outer join on these and ideally it will have all columns populated if keys match and NULL's on the other side if key doesnt match.

```
DF1
+----------------+
|Key | A | B | C |
|----------------|
|1  | v1 | z | a |
|2  | v2 | z | a |
|3  | v3 | z | b |
+----------------+


DF2
+----------------+
|Key | A | B | C |
|----------------|
|1  | v1 | z | a |
|5  | v1 | q | a |
|9  | v1 | z | v |
+----------------+

Full Outer joined DF

+---------------------------------+
|Key | A | B | C   | A | B | C    |
|---------------------------------|
|1  | v1 | z | a   | v1 | z  | a  |
|2  | v1 | q | a   |null|null|null|
|3  | v1 | z | v   |null|null|null|
|5  |null|null|null| v1 | q | a   |
|9  |null|null|null| v1 | z | v   |
+---------------------------------+


Expected DF

+----------------+
|Key | A | B | C |
|----------------|
|1  | v1 | z | a |
|2  | v2 | z | a |
|3  | v3 | z | b |
|5  | v1 | q | a |
|9  | v1 | z | v |
+----------------+
```

To achieve this we have to perform coalesce for all columns wherein if populated from left it takes it first or else will go to right df's value. But how do I apply coalesce dynamically to n number of attributes?

I couldnt find a way to first compare the similar columns of DF even assuming we did alias for both left and right DF's. Adding to that applying coalesce to each column. Please help me if my understanding is correct and a suitable approach for this pblm.

Comment: Looks like a UNION result. What's expected to happen if any of the non-key columns values don't match?

Comment: So, it should take priority of left DF and populate it.
Something like coalesce(leftdf.col1,rightdf.col1)